# How to debug CPP DLL from Java

Tags: java, c++

I have a Java code in which i am calling CPP DLL. Please help me out how I can debug this dll in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Do you have source code for the DLL? if not then you cannot debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to create a function in java that can be called by C asynchronously and prints the logs, make sure to attach and Detach thread of JVM properly

```
    public String logging( String logs )
{
//log.debug("................C Logging request..................");
if (logs.endsWith("\n"))
    logs = logs.substring(0, logs.length() - 1);
log.info("From C: " + logs);
return "SUCCESS";
}
```